# Unable to call some API's in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm dealing with a strange issue where I'm not able to hit some API's through iOS simulator in XCode.
Version: Xcode 10.3

I've tried using the following:

https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile2?symbol=GOOGL&token=
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

I'm able to hit both endpoints through the browser, replacing both with a completely unrelated api: https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts works, I'm able to see the response immediately as expected.

I've added the following to my Info.plist:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Code:

```
    let apiBaseUrl = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo"
    func getStock(symbol: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: apiBaseUrl) {
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
                data, res, err in
                if let error = err {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    var result: Any! = nil
                    
                    do
                    {
                        result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("exception: ")
                    }
                    print(result)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

In my console I see the following:

```
 HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

```
PAC result block not invoked
```

```
Received XPC error Connection invalid for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue as below :

I went into

System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies

and *unticked* **"Auto Proxy Discovery"**

My calls now work.